# Slow varchar index performance in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-like

I've got a table with ~500,000 rows with a column with values like `Brutus, Dreamer of the Wanton Wasteland`. I need to do a case-insensitive `LIKE` query on these, but it seems to perform very slowly. I tried making an index with:

```
create index name_idx on deck (name);
```

and

```
create index deck_name_idx on deck (lower(name));
```

But the query is equally slow either way. Here is my query:

```
select * 
    from deck 
    where lower(deck.name) like '%brutus, dreamer of the%' 
    order by deck.id desc 
    limit 20
```

Here are the results of my explain analyze (this is with the second index, but both are equally slow.)

```
Limit  (cost=152534.89..152537.23 rows=20 width=1496) (actual time=627.480..627.490 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=152534.89..152539.56 rows=40 width=1496) (actual time=627.479..627.488 rows=1 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=151534.87..151534.92 rows=20 width=1496) (actual time=611.447..611.447 rows=0 loops=3)
              Sort Key: id DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on deck  (cost=0.00..151534.44 rows=20 width=1496) (actual time=609.818..611.304 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Filter: (lower((name)::text) ~~ '%brutus, dreamer of the%'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 162210
Planning time: 0.786 ms
Execution time: 656.510 ms
```

Is there a better way to set up this index? If I have to I could denormalize the column to a lowercase version, but I'd rather not do that unless it will help a lot and there's no better way.

Comment: Why the `LIKE` if you don't have placeholders in the right operand?

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot those, and that changes the explain analyze results. Faster, actually, but still slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support `LIKE` queries with no wildcard in the beginning, use

```
CREATE INDEX ON deck (lower(name) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

To support `LIKE` searches that can have a wildcard at the beginning, you can

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON deck USING gin (lower(name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll take 11.5 ms execution time over 656 ms.